# Show the item in the sidebar drawer- Nested loop Vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, nested-loops, sidebar, slidingdrawer

I was trying to show the items in their appropriate drawer when I click on the button in the sidebar, but I just keep looping all the items in one drawer and each button on sidebar seem like doesn't have their own drawer.

**Here is my screen**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxXRc.png

**and this is my code**

```
<template>
<div class="flex-column">
    <!-- top navigation bar -->

 <!-- side navigation bar -->
        <div class="container mx-0" style="width:100%; max-width: 100vw">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sidenav col-1 px-0">
                    <div class="flex-column menu" id="menu">
                        <button @click="backHome()" style="padding: 6px 19px"><i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i>Home</button>                           
                     
                        <button v-for="drawer in drawers" :key="drawer.id" :class="{activeBtn:drawer.id == selected}" @click.prevent="activated(drawer.id)" >
                            <span v-html="drawer.icon"></span>{{drawer.text}}
                        </button>
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div v-if="!active" class="sub-sidenav col-3" >
                    <div class="flex-column">
                         <div class="form-group has-search">
                            <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text" placeholder="Search...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row p-3">
                            <div v-for="drawer in drawers" :key="drawer.id">
                                <div class="column" v-for="item in drawer.items" :key="item.id">
                                    <div class="card" style="width: 7rem;height: 7rem">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <span class="center" v-html="item.svg"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="space col-8">
                    <div class="workspace"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
 </div>
</template>
```

**script**

```
<script>
export default {


    data() {
        return{
            selected: undefined,
            active: 'false',
            drawers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    text: "Character",
                    icon: '<i class="fas fa-users fa-2x"></i>',
                    items: [
                        {
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="43.808" height="145.733" viewBox="0 0 43.808 145.733">' +
                                ' <g id="Group_9" data-name="Group 9" transform="translate(-1183.765 -369.402)">' +
                                        '<path id="Path_84" data-name="Path 84" d="M568.051,437.983a3.832,3.832,0,0,0,2.548-2.014,3.887,3.887,0,0,0,.1-3.263l14.106-32.131-8.069-2.049-11.328,32.228a3.892,3.892,0,0,0-1.865,4.8,3.841,3.841,0,0,0,4.5,2.432Z" transform="translate(626.349 12.29)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_85" data-name="Path 85" d="M596.337,403.246l-7.848-3.7a1.737,1.737,0,0,1-.7-2.522l4.77-7.262a4.748,4.748,0,0,1,6.342-2.3,4.821,4.821,0,0,1,2.277,6.394l-2.466,8.318a1.725,1.725,0,0,1-.942,1.083A1.7,1.7,0,0,1,596.337,403.246Z" transform="translate(610.773 19.676)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_86" data-name="Path 86" d="M335.588,436.026h-4.367l-2.077-16.982h6.445Z" transform="translate(875.771 74.841)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_87" data-name="Path 87" d="M601.913,678.834h-14.08v-.18a5.5,5.5,0,0,1,5.481-5.525h8.6Z" transform="translate(610.56 -163.699)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_88" data-name="Path 88" d="M376.588,436.026h-4.367l-2.077-16.982h6.445Z" transform="translate(849.374 74.841)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_89" data-name="Path 89" d="M642.913,678.834h-14.08v-.18a5.5,5.5,0,0,1,5.48-5.525h8.6Z" transform="translate(584.164 -163.699)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_90" data-name="Path 90" d="M616.008,525.689q-.059,0-.119,0l-5.022-.375a1.617,1.617,0,0,1-1.448-1.268L600.7,475.788a.534.534,0,0,0-1.055.157l3.1,47.544a1.624,1.624,0,0,1-.421,1.224,1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.177.519H597.32a1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.493-1.027c-9.617-25.391-6.134-75.143-6.107-75.643l.356-.359h0l19.155,3.335.041.04c6.545,4.847,9.377,61.606,8.336,72.4a1.943,1.943,0,0,1-.474,1.245,1.6,1.6,0,0,1-1.126.465Z" transform="translate(609.755 -19.546)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<ellipse id="Ellipse_17" data-name="Ellipse 17" cx="8.748" cy="8.82" rx="8.748" ry="8.82" transform="translate(1192.936 381.911)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_91" data-name="Path 91" d="M609.9,406.117a1.321,1.321,0,0,1-.265-.027l-22.468-2.907a1.889,1.889,0,0,1-1.335-2.014l2.15-11.968c-2.85-3.591-.157-12.866,1.584-15.21l-.673-1.837a2.3,2.3,0,0,1-.03-1.483,1.817,1.817,0,0,1,.846-1.074l9.118-4.884a1.509,1.509,0,0,1,2.115.987l1.788,4.879-.027.014c4.282,2.314,8.075,4.6,5.226,16.813l3.572,16.863a2.1,2.1,0,0,1-.594,1.418A1.445,1.445,0,0,1,609.9,406.117Z" transform="translate(611.851 34.067)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_92" data-name="Path 92" d="M553.047,416.918a3.759,3.759,0,0,1,.4.441l17.622-1.228,1.89-3.884,6.187,2.11-2.684,7.2a2.849,2.849,0,0,1-2.883,1.854l-20.039-1.532a3.723,3.723,0,0,1-4,1.438,3.78,3.78,0,0,1-.693-7.017,3.715,3.715,0,0,1,4.207.613Z" transform="translate(637 3.497)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_93" data-name="Path 93" d="M613.881,399.861a1.626,1.626,0,0,1,.052-1.345l3.634-7.236a4.444,4.444,0,0,1,5.621-2.857,4.5,4.5,0,0,1,2.834,5.667l-1.4,8.014a1.616,1.616,0,0,1-.758,1.108,1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.327.145l-7.681-2.578a1.606,1.606,0,0,1-.976-.918Z" transform="translate(593.868 18.911)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                        '<ellipse id="Ellipse_18" data-name="Ellipse 18" cx="7.124" cy="7.182" rx="7.124" ry="7.182" transform="translate(1199.474 369.402)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                        '<path id="Path_94" data-name="Path 94" d="M567.6,323.04a3.7,3.7,0,0,1-2.062-.174A2.47,2.47,0,0,1,564.312,321c-1.327-8.891,6.172-8.16,7.059-8.545a9.724,9.724,0,0,0,1.568-1.154,7.283,7.283,0,0,1,4.1-.909,11.724,11.724,0,0,1,4.979.614,7.481,7.481,0,0,1,3.309,3.075,15.6,15.6,0,0,1,1.641,4.285,10.778,10.778,0,0,1,.279,5.253,6.455,6.455,0,0,1-5.848,4.725,4.873,4.873,0,0,0-2.544-5.324,7.3,7.3,0,0,0-4.85-.582,21.183,21.183,0,0,1-3.217.4C569.724,322.886,568.451,322.949,567.6,323.04Z" transform="translate(625.804 68.782)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                        {
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60.573" height="139.408" viewBox="0 0 60.573 139.408">' +
                                '<g id="Group_10" data-name="Group 10" transform="translate(-364.839 -95.836)">' +
                                    '<path id="Path_101" data-name="Path 101" d="M406.917,367.962a3.321,3.321,0,0,0-2.721,1.012,3.674,3.674,0,0,0-1.007,2.835l-11.1,5.118,5.294,3.581,9.727-5.409a3.618,3.618,0,0,0-.2-7.137Z" transform="translate(15.37 -246.348)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_26" data-name="Ellipse 26" cx="8.334" cy="8.733" rx="8.334" ry="8.733" transform="translate(369.187 97.763)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_102" data-name="Path 102" d="M110.666,433.556h4.16l1.979-16.814h-6.14Z" transform="translate(281.939 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_103" data-name="Path 103" d="M345.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H345.178Z" transform="translate(46.365 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_104" data-name="Path 104" d="M59.666,433.556h4.16L65.8,416.742h-6.14Z" transform="translate(315.633 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_105" data-name="Path 105" d="M294.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H294.178Z" transform="translate(80.06 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_106" data-name="Path 106" d="M293.522,546.53a1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.195l-.2-63.006,21.724-.877.16-.006,3.573,37.793.448,24.076a1.572,1.572,0,0,1-1.348,1.62l-5.273.65a1.479,1.479,0,0,1-1.171-.373,1.629,1.629,0,0,1-.533-1.154l-.939-25.578-4.558-15.924a.5.5,0,0,0-.558-.3.526.526,0,0,0-.411.5l-1.774,41.872a1.569,1.569,0,0,1-1.338,1.506l-6.089.785a1.477,1.477,0,0,1-1.2-.388Z" transform="translate(80.965 -319.492)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_107" data-name="Path 107" d="M277.416,405.1l-6.436-27.389c-2.005-8.534,2.576-17.127,10.212-19.155a12.475,12.475,0,0,1,10.556,1.972,15.823,15.823,0,0,1,6.338,10.948l4.2,32.424a1.653,1.653,0,0,1-.35,1.252,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.123.563l-21.879.6h-.04A1.552,1.552,0,0,1,277.416,405.1Z" transform="translate(95.698 -240.023)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_108" data-name="Path 108" d="M332.544,384.227l-16.317-8.305a5.871,5.871,0,0,1-.151-10.254,5.272,5.272,0,0,1,5.732.413l13.2,9.88,14.252-5.947a1.473,1.473,0,0,1,1.673.386l1.922,2.126a1.648,1.648,0,0,1,.408,1.285,1.612,1.612,0,0,1-.679,1.153l-12.759,8.772a7.134,7.134,0,0,1-7.283.491Z" transform="translate(67.532 -244.457)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_109" data-name="Path 109" d="M281.411,314.339a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-1.9-.411c-.266-.122-.542-.223-.807-.346-2.343-1.083-3.886-4.067-3.941-7.071a11.032,11.032,0,0,1,3.176-7.84,11.188,11.188,0,0,1,6.936-3.136c2.7-.246,5.735.573,7.242,3.26a3.269,3.269,0,0,1,.444,2.447,1.622,1.622,0,0,1-.369.678c-.673.716-1.344.178-2.03.13-.943-.065-1.79.848-2.095,1.918a6.866,6.866,0,0,0,.075,3.339l0,.02a1.9,1.9,0,0,1-.29,1.484,1.731,1.731,0,0,1-1.258.747,7.768,7.768,0,0,1-2.5,0,1.372,1.372,0,0,0-1.864.451,2.8,2.8,0,0,0-.236.814c-.332,1.812-.256,1.7-.588,3.516Z" transform="translate(92.887 -199.658)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_110" data-name="Path 110" d="M275.343,498.593a3.712,3.712,0,0,0,.582-2.963,3.55,3.55,0,0,0-1.794-2.37l1.563-12.6-5.663,2.894-.616,11.521a3.68,3.68,0,0,0,1.473,4.518,3.332,3.332,0,0,0,4.456-1Z" transform="translate(96.598 -318.986)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_111" data-name="Path 111" d="M274.229,423.209a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.318.078l-5.716.757a1.481,1.481,0,0,1-1.2-.388,1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.2l.045-41.822a5,5,0,0,1,4.126-4.987h0a4.675,4.675,0,0,1,4.011,1.343,5.182,5.182,0,0,1,1.469,4.135l-1.661,18.023.778,22.5a1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.016,1.567Z" transform="translate(98.362 -251.277)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    text: "Element",
                    icon: '<i class="fas fa-vector-square fa-2x"></i>',
                    items: [
                        {
                            svg: '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="60.573" height="139.408" viewBox="0 0 60.573 139.408">' +
                                '<g id="Group_10" data-name="Group 10" transform="translate(-364.839 -95.836)">' +
                                    '<path id="Path_101" data-name="Path 101" d="M406.917,367.962a3.321,3.321,0,0,0-2.721,1.012,3.674,3.674,0,0,0-1.007,2.835l-11.1,5.118,5.294,3.581,9.727-5.409a3.618,3.618,0,0,0-.2-7.137Z" transform="translate(15.37 -246.348)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<ellipse id="Ellipse_26" data-name="Ellipse 26" cx="8.334" cy="8.733" rx="8.334" ry="8.733" transform="translate(369.187 97.763)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_102" data-name="Path 102" d="M110.666,433.556h4.16l1.979-16.814h-6.14Z" transform="translate(281.939 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_103" data-name="Path 103" d="M345.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H345.178Z" transform="translate(46.365 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_104" data-name="Path 104" d="M59.666,433.556h4.16L65.8,416.742h-6.14Z" transform="translate(315.633 -202.537)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_105" data-name="Path 105" d="M294.178,671.685h8.193a5.35,5.35,0,0,1,5.221,5.471v.178H294.178Z" transform="translate(80.06 -442.089)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_106" data-name="Path 106" d="M293.522,546.53a1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.195l-.2-63.006,21.724-.877.16-.006,3.573,37.793.448,24.076a1.572,1.572,0,0,1-1.348,1.62l-5.273.65a1.479,1.479,0,0,1-1.171-.373,1.629,1.629,0,0,1-.533-1.154l-.939-25.578-4.558-15.924a.5.5,0,0,0-.558-.3.526.526,0,0,0-.411.5l-1.774,41.872a1.569,1.569,0,0,1-1.338,1.506l-6.089.785a1.477,1.477,0,0,1-1.2-.388Z" transform="translate(80.965 -319.492)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_107" data-name="Path 107" d="M277.416,405.1l-6.436-27.389c-2.005-8.534,2.576-17.127,10.212-19.155a12.475,12.475,0,0,1,10.556,1.972,15.823,15.823,0,0,1,6.338,10.948l4.2,32.424a1.653,1.653,0,0,1-.35,1.252,1.5,1.5,0,0,1-1.123.563l-21.879.6h-.04A1.552,1.552,0,0,1,277.416,405.1Z" transform="translate(95.698 -240.023)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_108" data-name="Path 108" d="M332.544,384.227l-16.317-8.305a5.871,5.871,0,0,1-.151-10.254,5.272,5.272,0,0,1,5.732.413l13.2,9.88,14.252-5.947a1.473,1.473,0,0,1,1.673.386l1.922,2.126a1.648,1.648,0,0,1,.408,1.285,1.612,1.612,0,0,1-.679,1.153l-12.759,8.772a7.134,7.134,0,0,1-7.283.491Z" transform="translate(67.532 -244.457)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_109" data-name="Path 109" d="M281.411,314.339a4.21,4.21,0,0,1-1.9-.411c-.266-.122-.542-.223-.807-.346-2.343-1.083-3.886-4.067-3.941-7.071a11.032,11.032,0,0,1,3.176-7.84,11.188,11.188,0,0,1,6.936-3.136c2.7-.246,5.735.573,7.242,3.26a3.269,3.269,0,0,1,.444,2.447,1.622,1.622,0,0,1-.369.678c-.673.716-1.344.178-2.03.13-.943-.065-1.79.848-2.095,1.918a6.866,6.866,0,0,0,.075,3.339l0,.02a1.9,1.9,0,0,1-.29,1.484,1.731,1.731,0,0,1-1.258.747,7.768,7.768,0,0,1-2.5,0,1.372,1.372,0,0,0-1.864.451,2.8,2.8,0,0,0-.236.814c-.332,1.812-.256,1.7-.588,3.516Z" transform="translate(92.887 -199.658)" fill="#2f2e41"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_110" data-name="Path 110" d="M275.343,498.593a3.712,3.712,0,0,0,.582-2.963,3.55,3.55,0,0,0-1.794-2.37l1.563-12.6-5.663,2.894-.616,11.521a3.68,3.68,0,0,0,1.473,4.518,3.332,3.332,0,0,0,4.456-1Z" transform="translate(96.598 -318.986)" fill="#fff5cd"/>' +
                                    '<path id="Path_111" data-name="Path 111" d="M274.229,423.209a1.5,1.5,0,0,1-.318.078l-5.716.757a1.481,1.481,0,0,1-1.2-.388,1.634,1.634,0,0,1-.517-1.2l.045-41.822a5,5,0,0,1,4.126-4.987h0a4.675,4.675,0,0,1,4.011,1.343,5.182,5.182,0,0,1,1.469,4.135l-1.661,18.023.778,22.5a1.591,1.591,0,0,1-1.016,1.567Z" transform="translate(98.362 -251.277)" fill="#fbad6b"/>' +
                                '</g>' +
                                '</svg>'
                        },
                    ]
                    
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    text: "Background",
                    icon: '<i class="far fa-file-image fa-2x"></i>',
                }
            ],
          
        }
    },

    methods: {
        backHome() {
             this.$router.push('/'); 
        },

        activated(id) {
            this.drawers.find(drawer => drawer.id === id)
            this.selected = id;

            if(id = 1){
                this.active = !this.active;
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Please help me if you have any solution or ideas to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you should include in your `drawers` array of objects is a value (preferably a boolean) that keeps track of which sidebar button was clicked. The reason why all the icons are being looped right now is that you don't filter them.

Here's an example of what you can have as the structure for your `drawers`

```js
drawers: [{
    id
    text
    icon
    clickedDrawer # keeps track which drawer was specifically clicked on so we can decide on which drawer's svg to display
},...
]
```

In your template

```html
<div v-for="drawer in drawers" :key="drawer.id">
                                <div v-if="drawer.id === selected">
                                    ### REST OF YOUR CODE                                
                                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which means I have to define different "clickedDrawer" in each array such as clickedDrawer1, clickedDrawer2....something like this, am I right?

Comment: No, each object in your `drawers` array should have a `clickedDrawer` property, if they have different properties (which would happen if you put `clickedDrawer1`, `clickedDrawer2`, etc. then you need to take into account of that in your `v-if` statements

Comment: I see, may I know should I put the active: 'false' for each array or I just keep it outside?

Comment: I try to do a function like this in the method :  if(this.selected = id){
              
                this.active = !this.active;
            }, but seem like I used the wrong way.

Comment: Can you try to have a `v-if` tag which is below the `v-for` tag for displaying drawers which checks if `drawer.id === selected`, I've updated my code to show an example

Comment: So now you don't need `clickedDrawer` what you just need to do is make sure while you are displaying the drawers, the following must be true `drawer.id === selected`

Comment: Thanks!! It's work! I have another question, now each drawer shows its own items, but when I click on another button, it will close the previous drawer and need to click again to open it, I can't directly open the next drawer, may I know what should I do with this?